# SCSI read(10) reads out weird values- USB pendrive

Tags: embedded, usb, fat32, scsi

I am implementing USB as a host using OHCI to read the files stored in the Flashdrive. To read I implement the read(10) command in SCSI. The Logical Block address being the sector number. The following is an image of the command I send for read(10) to read LBA 0x0000-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pCYJ.png

I read 512bytes(size of one sector or 1 LBA)and the following is the output that i get for LBA 0x0000-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Rpr.jpg

The bytes in the above image are not present any where on the pendrive, I checked that using HXD. Now, for testing I filled the pendrive to full capacity. If I read any other LBA, other than 0x0000, then I always get 512 bytes of 0x00.

Could anyone please tell me what the problem could be?
Am I supposed to execute some other command before I do a read(10) so that the USB sends me the right data maybe?

From my understanding I have put DPO, FUA and FUA_NV=0 and also RDPROTECT=2

Comment: @duskwuff would u know anything about this?

Comment: If you are prepared to tackle this task, you are certainly capable of getting your output in a textual form and including it within the body of your question.  As for your question, there are many open-source implementations of what you are trying to do, and reading one might be informative.  Those for smaller systems may be simpler to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't properly read the boot sector from a FAT32 USB drive on Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323088/cant-properly-read-the-boot-sector-from-a-fat32-usb-drive-on-android-device)

Comment: Question has the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29330720/410847) as [29323088](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29323088/410847). Vote to close.